# Executable file to run java on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, minecraft

I'm trying to make a simple file so I can call it in SSH and it will start my minecraft server.
I tried making a batch file called start.bat with this code:

> java -Xmx512M -Xmx512M -jar craftbukkit-1.2.5-R1.0.jar nogui

However, when I run it in SSH:

> $ cd /Minecraft/server_1/
>
> $ start.bat

The SSH returns that it is an invalid or unknown command. Is there any other way I can make a quick command/file to start my server? What file extensions would I use to get this working? It works if I paste that java command in SSH and run it, but I'd rather have a file.

Comment: .. why did'nt you include the error message while you were there? It would have been one more line...

Comment: No, SSH just said that "start.bat is an unknown command"

Comment: Incidentally, `ssh` didn't say anything -- it was `bash` that reported the command wasn't known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current working directory is *not* included in your `PATH` by default because it is a security risk on multiuser systems. (And a potential annoyance even on machines that are single user.) You would use `./start.bat` to start the program.

Since you're using Windows naming conventions, I presume you also forgot to set the execution mode bit -- and you probably also forgot the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of the file.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx512M -Xmx512M -jar craftbukkit-1.2.5-R1.0.jar nogui
```

Run `chmod 500` on this file. (Strictly speaking, `555` could also work, if you didn't mind other people on the machine executing the file. But they don't need to, so don't let them.) See the `chmod(1)` manpage for more details on the modes -- `1` bits mean *executable*, `2` bits means *writable*, and `4` bits means `readable` -- thus, `5` is *executable and readable*.

Then, when you want to run the script, run it like this:

```
cd /Minecraft/server_1
./start.bat
```

Note the `./` -- that means the shell should start the search for the executable program in the current working directory. (It could be `./bin/start.bat` if your current working directory had a `bin` subdirectory with a `start.bat` executable file.)

Answer (score 2):

Is start.bat executable?  Make sure you have #!/bin/sh as the first line of the file.  Also the directory is probably not in in the path, so try this:

```
    $ chmod 555 start.bat
    $ ./start.bat
```